# Find the criteria on a variable

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

What would the criteria on the variable $v$ be such that $f\left( t\right) $
is always negative .
$$f\left( t\right) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\frac{\cos \left( xt\right) }{x^{v}}%
dx=\frac{\Gamma \left( k+v\right) }{\Gamma \left( v\right) }\frac{1}{t^{k}}%
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\frac{\cos \left( xt-\frac{k\pi }{2}\right) }{x^{v+k}}dx
$$